# Perform operation in Data table based on more than one constraint in R

Tags: r, data.table

Normally when I perform operations on data table its on one constraint e.g

```
 setDT(df)[, mean.price := mean(Price), by = Id]
```

this command get the mean of price based on unique `Id`. My question is that if there is a way to mention two constraints in the command e.g

```
setDT(df)[, mean.price := mean(Price), by = Id & Year]
```

So I can get the mean of rows with same `Id` belonging to same `Year`.

Suppose I have following data frame

```
Id Price Year
1  5     2003
1  10    2003
1  4     2003
1  6     2004
1  6     2004
1  10    2004
2  7     2003
2  10    2003
2  3     2003
2  2     2004
2  3     2004
2  10    2004
```

so the resultant data frame will look like

```
Id Price Year  Mean.Price
1  5     2003  6.33
1  10    2003  6.33
1  4     2003  6.33
1  6     2004  7.33
1  6     2004  7.33
1  10    2004  7.33
2  7     2003  7
2  10    2003  7
2  4     2003  7
2  2     2004  5
2  3     2004  5
2  10    2004  5
```

Comment: I guess you need `setDT(df)[, Mean.Price := mean(Price), by = .(Id, Year)]`  If you want to specify the `names` i.e. `setDT(df)[, Mean.Price := mean(Price), c(names(df)[c(1,3)])]`

Comment: Did you read `?data.table`? There are many examples for such an operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either write it like akrun wrote it:

```
setDT(df)[, mean.price := mean(Price), by = .(Id,Year)]
```

or with the names as vector:

```
setDT(df)[, mean.price := mean(Price), by = c("Id","Year")]
```